# Oracle sql - concatenate all columns

Tags: sql, oracle

Am having a table with 30+ columns. Would like to append all the column data.

I'm currently using multiple concatenate operators to achieve this in Oracle.

Example :
`SELECT C1.data || '' || C2.data ||..........Cm.data
FROM C`

Is there any other way of doing it with out using the '||' - concatenate operator multiple times ? I want to achieve this using query. (Not interested in post processing using any language) Any assistance would be of great help.

Comment: How about [concat()](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions026.htm)  ? Ofcourse the behaviour is same..

Comment: Using concat() will save me the pain of using multiple '||' operators. Is there any other way to concatenate all the columns in a table without specifying all the column names (As we are going to concatenate all the columns in that table) ?

Comment: What are you going to do with the data once you have selected it? Chances are that the "problem" of "not having to use using the || operator multiple times..." will go away if you changed your approach.

Comment: CONCAT only supports two arguments, so it will make everything worse in every possible way.

Comment: I strike my query in an online SQL tool. Use the results for data analytics.

Comment: Was wondering if Oracle had any inbuilt functionality for my problem.

Comment: Don't your analysis tool want separate columns?

Comment: Nope. It needs them concatenated.

Comment: So you enter a query, the online SQL tool generates the data and then what? You copy & paste the data in the analysis tool? Or the analysis tool somehow consumes the data generated on that page?

Comment: Concatenate them in a view, then select from that view

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this. Anyway you'll be mentioning all the columns you needed.

```
declare
stmt varchar2(300);
v_char char(10):=',||" "||,';
begin
stmt:='select 1,2,3,4 from tab';
dbms_output.put_line(stmt);
select replace(stmt,',',v_char) into stmt from dual;
dbms_output.put_line(stmt);
execute immediate stmt; // you can add this after verifying your query 
 end;
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
select 1,||" "||, 2,||" "||, 3,||" "||, 4 from tab;
```